# Reverse a sin and cos transform

Tags: math, trigonometry

I'm manipulating a 2D map with basic sin and cos quite successfully to give a 3d perspective.

The issue I'm having is I'm stuck trying to find what is visible in the viewport.
Effectively doing the transformation in reverse, the output is [0,0] and [width,height] and I want to know where on my map those points lie.

I've got it to the point of trying to reverse:

```
display_x = (source_x * cos(z)) + (source_y * sin(z))
display_y = (source_y * cos(z)) - (source_x * sin(z))
```

If I know `display_x` and `display_y` and `source_x` and `source_y` are the unknowns, how can I solve what the unknowns are?
My simultaneous equation knowledge is a little rusty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're effectively using a 2d rotation matrix 
(I'm pretty sure you have a typo where you swapped source_x for source_y in the definition of display_y)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

```
[ cos(z), sin(z) ] [ source_x ] = [ display_x ]
[-sin(z), cos(z) ] [ source_y ]   [ display_y ]
```

all you need to do to invert this matrix is find it's transpose (flipped over the diagonal) because it's guaranteed to be orthogonal.

so it should be:

```
display_x = (source_x * cos(z)) - (source_y * sin(z)) 
display_y = (source_x * sin(z)) + (source_y * cos(z))
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. I noticed you copied the same typo in your response. :)

Comment: I think I just swapped the order - source_x is there :) It's interesting that Thomas Andrew's response is also right because cos(z) == cos(-z) so really you're just moving the sign of sin(z)

Answer (score 2):

Your transformation is rotation by angle z, so you need to reverse by rotating by angle -z. This yields:

```
source_x = (display_x * cos(z)) - (display_y * sin(z))
source_y = (display_x * cos(z)) + (display_y * sin(z))
```

This uses that:

```
cos(z) == cos(-z)
sin(-z) == -sin(z)
```